# Creating images from Jekyll posts

Tags: jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I am looking to "automatically" create images from Jekyll posts. Either dynamically or on site build, I am not picky. I know I can create images from html and css, so this must be possible, but I am not sure where to start to do it in Jekyll. 
From what I can tell this seems like it would have to be when the site builds since I don't know of any way to return an image using a static page haha.

Comment: This might be a good start: http://www.cherpec.com/2013/04/30/capturing-web-page-screenshots-from-ruby/

Comment: It does look like a very good starting point. They already have a gem for it and everything. Unfortunately I am not strong enough in ruby to pursue it myself though so I might just have to call this one a pipe dream.